# Finding the fourier series of floor function

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the fourier series for $f(x)=\cases{x-[x]\quad x\in\mathbb{R\setminus Z} \\ \frac 1 2\quad x\in\mathbb{Z}}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and its values for $x=1.5,3,5$.

In order to find the series I need to find fourier coefficients but that's not clear to me how to inetegrate $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)dx$. I thought dividing it to $$\int_{x\in\mathbb Z} \frac 1 2dx+\underbrace{\int_{z\notin\mathbb Z}(x-[x])\cos(nx)dx}_{=2\pi\int_0^1(x-[x])\cos(nx)dx}$$but then I can't deal with the last integral (first is integration on set of measure zero so it equals 0). Furthermomre, suppose I found the series, since this function is continuous at almost every point can I say that substituting the x values is sufficient (i.e the series is uniformally convergent to the function on the interval)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One have to cut the integrals in a sum of segments where the floor function is constant on each :

[image]

The result has been checked with several numerical tests.

Other examples corresponding to the particular values requested in the wording of the question :

[image]

There is a typing mistake in the table above. Please, replace $4$ by $5$. Sorry, I didn't succeed to correct it because I cannot replace the page by a corrected page (bug each time).

[image]

Comment: thanks. I had mistake in typing the question (sorry). why you did integration on these segments which include both integers and rationals?

Comment: The integration is on $-\pi<x<\pi$ as it is specified in the wording of your question. The function to be integrated is a peicewise function. So, the integral is cut in as many pieces than they are pieces. The boudaries of each piece are integers because the floor function changes of value for integer values of $x$, except the pieces at left and right ends where the bounds are $x=-\pi$ and $x=\pi$ respectively.

Comment: and neglecting the integral on $\mathbb{Z}$ is correct?

Comment: Nothing is neglected. The bound of the integral is included in the integral. Another manner to understand it is to consider an integral limited to a point only. It's value is $0$ because the extand of the range of integration is $0$ and the value $f(x)$ of the function at this point $x$ is finite : $f(x)*0=0$. This is true because we know that $f(x)$ is finite.

Comment: so the integral on the "constant" points equal to 0 so we are left with the integral of the $x-[x]$? thanks again.

Comment: What you call "constant" points at the left and/or right bounds of an integral can be consider as included or not included in the integral. This changes nothing insofar the function is finite at these points.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, being discontinuous, the series can't be uniformly convergent. Secondly, you need to be sure which definition of the floor function you are using. For one definition, floor is odd, and therefore the value of the integral is zero. For the other you get

$\newcommand{\dx}{\,\mathbb d x}$
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \cos x \dx =\int_{-\pi}^{-3} -4\cos x \dx + \int_{-3}^{-2} -3\cos x \dx + \int_{-2}^{-1} -2\cos x \dx + \int_{-1}^{0} -1\cos x \dx + \int_{1}^{2} \cos x \dx + \int_{2}^{3} 2\cos x \dx + \int_{3}^{\pi} 3\cos x \dx$$

Comment: about the convergence: can't you define $$f(x)=\underbrace{g(x)}_{=x}+\underbrace{h(x)}_{\text{x-[x] if not integer}}$$? furtherore: suppose if x is integer the function would have got constant value, how then I'd solve it?

Comment: In the above, $x$ is real, going between the limits of the integral. The Fourier Series is a sequence of continuous functions. The function you are approximating is discontinuous. It can be proved that the Fourier Series will converge pointwise to the discontinuous function, but the fact that it is continuous means that it cannot converge uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the graph of $f$ one immediately remarks that $f(x)=-{1\over2}+{\rm odd}(x)$, so that apart from the constant term we only have sine coefficients
$$b_k={2\over\pi}\int_0^\pi \bigl(\lfloor x\rfloor+{1\over2}\bigr)\ dx\qquad(k\geq1)\ .$$
For the computation of the $b_k$ see JJacquelin's answer.

It remains to answer the additional questions. When a function $f$ is periodic and smooth apart from finitely many jump discontinuities per period  then its Fourier series $s(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ at all points of continuity and to ${1\over2}\bigl(f(\xi-)+f(\xi+)\bigr)$ at the jump points $\xi$. It follows that
$$s(1.5)=f(1.5)=1, \quad s(3)={1\over2}\bigl(f(3-)+f(3+)\bigr)=2.5$$
and
$$ s(5)=s(5-2\pi)=s(-1.28\ldots)=f(-1.28\ldots)=-2\ .$$

Comment: You are right. It was not necessary to compute $a_n$ which obviously are $=0$ except for $n=0$. It is also obvious that $a_0=-\frac{1}{2}$ considering the symetry of the floor function relatively to the point $(x=0,y=-\frac{1}{2})$